# Displaying text from another activity on a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to use `putExtra()` and `getExtra()` to send `String Data` from one activity to another, such that the retrieved string is to be displayed on a `TextView` and when running. 
When i run the program i get a `classCastException` on `onCreate()` method.

I am new to android so any assistance will be appreciated.

Here is my sample code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sales); 

    //TextView
    TextView model1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.model1);
    TextView model2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.model2);
    TextView model3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.model3);

    //Bundle
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String Mod1 = bundle.getString("model1");
    String Mod2 = bundle.getString("model2");
    String Mod3 = bundle.getString("model3");

//setting values            
model1.setText(Mod1);               
model2.setText(Mod2);               
model3.setText(Mod3);
   }
```

Comment: On what line are you getting the error? In any case, sounds like either model1 or model2 or model3 is not a TextView.

Comment: Post your logcat please and specify the expression that fires the exception

Comment: show how you called the intent?

Answer (score 2):

Your widgets model1,model2,model3 are either not `TextView` or you do not pass strings to the intent that you pass to the new `Activity`. Also you could try to clean your projects, maybe your `R.java` file is messed up. You could also paste the LogCat or tell us which is the line that gives you the `ClassCastException`.

Comment: It's the widgets. Intent.getString() would return null if there is no String with that key.

Comment: You guys rock...the widget i was pointing to was not a TextView but an Edittext that goes along with my implementaton. I have managed to get the strings after changing the widgets to point to the textview. i really appreiate guys...lets keep up the name of android

Comment: you can accept the answer if this helped you solve the problem